# AWS file upload with nodejs api not working

Tags: node.js, angularjs, amazon-s3

I want to upload the images of my project to S3 of AWS through my angle and nodejs + express project.
I made this method to upload the images that seems not to be working

```
require("dotenv").config();
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

BUCKET = 'my-bucket-name'

exports.uploadFile = async (file, folder) => {
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: process.env.REGION
      })

      var s3 = new AWS.S3()

      s3.putObject({
        Bucket: BUCKET,
        Key: folder + "/" + file.name,
        Body: file,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        ContentType: file.contentType
      })
        .promise()
        .then(response => {
          console.log(`done! - `, response)
          console.log(
            `The URL is ${s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', { Bucket: BUCKET, Key: folder + "/" + file.namey })}`
          )
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('failed:', err)
        })
}
```

I call it from the frontend project from this endpoint.

```
  uploadFile(file, folder) {
    return this.requestService.request('POST', `${environment.endpoint}/upload`, {file: file, folder: folder}, {}, false);
  }
```

Front component methods:

```
  upload() {
    const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    this.uploadService.uploadFile(file, this.type);
  }

  selectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  }
```

I've tried if the image isn't working from the frontend but it's working, but in backend I received an "undefined". Why is the backend not receiving it well?

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: There are no error messages, just an "undefined" is stored in s3. Saving seems to be done but the file is "undefined"